# Type error is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid, scripting

I am using below code to get list of selected checkboxes. deleteItem method is called onclick of a button.

```
function deleteItem(){

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")){

         var selected = new Array();
         $('checkbox:checked').each(function() {
         selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
         });
         alert(selected);
         deleteAll(selected,0);
        }
        }
```

In console I am getting error like

```
 TypeError: $(...) is null


$(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
```

What is wrong in code?

Comment: and what is `$(...)`?

Comment: one reason I could see is `$` is not refering jQuery, can you try with `jQuery(':checkbox:checked')...`

Comment: $(':checkbox:checked').each(function() ... this is coming as null. I have selected few checkboxes from the grid. So it shouldn't be null right?

Comment: your code above does not have the `:` from `checkbox`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't selected element/s.

`$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')`

It means: take all `checkbox` elements (`input` elements with `checkbox` type), then filter all of the checked `checkbox` elements and return an array with that elements.

Comment: Where I have to add this line?

Comment: instead of `$(':checkbox:checked')`

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
$('input:checkbox:checked')
```

instead of

```
$(':checkbox:checked')
```